# Build url of publishing page by lookup id

Tags: javascript, csom, publishing-page, hyperlink, id

Got a list with a LookupField to Publishing Pages library pointing on "Title" and additional field "ID". 
I would like to create a hyperlink by CSOM / javascript **without querying FileRef** on pages library.
Is it possible to build the url of the page referenced in my list item using lookup id?